# Forward domain for flavors.me yet retain own_domain.com/blog

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, seo

I wish to have my flavors.me use my own domain, yet still wish to retain access to `own_domain.com/blog`

The way flavors.me works now is that I must have the DNS A record point at their IP. Which obviously will prevent me from still having access to own_domain.com/blog

Am posting this to gather some ideas. What ought to be the best way of solving this?

I am trying to stave off the need for a subdomain for the blog if I can help it.

Is there some magic with htaccess and domain masking that can occur without SEO penalties?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If they must have an A or CNAME record pointing to their service, you cannot have it at the same FQDN as your existing site, period.

blog.own_domain.com would solve your problem; you can set up an .htaccess giving an HTTP 301 redirect on www.own_domain.com/blog pointing to blog.own_domain.com.

Content of your new .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/blog(.*)$ http://blog.own_domain.com/$1 [R=301,E]
```

The `(.*)$` and `$1` catch anything after /blog and include it at the end of the new URL.

If that doesn't seem to work, try this instead:

```
REDIRECT 301 /blog http://blog.own_domain.com/
```

If the content is dynamic, use this instead, adjusting as needed:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=13$
RewriteRule ^/page.php$ http://www.example.com/newname.htm? [L,R=301]
```

Using 301 should not affect your SEO. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Comment: @romant: If this helped you, mark it accepted. Thanks!